# p xor q xor r -- simplifying into disjunctive normal form with propositional algebra

Tags: propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

So, I have $p \oplus q \oplus r$, and my goal is to simplify into disjunctive normal form with propositional algebra.

Step 1: simplyify xor 
((($p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q))) \vee r)  $

Step 2: distribute the NOT on the left hand side 
((($p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) \wedge \neg r) \vee ((\neg(p \wedge \neg q) \wedge \neg(\neg p \wedge q)) \vee r))$

Step 3: distribute the NOTs on the left side again 
((($p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) \wedge \neg r) \vee (((\neg p \vee q) \wedge ( p \vee \neg q)) \vee r))$

Step 4: distribute r on both sides 
$ ((\neg r \wedge (p \wedge q)) \vee (\neg r \wedge(\neg p \wedge q))) \vee ((r \vee (\neg p \vee q))  \wedge (r \vee(p \vee \neg q))) $

Step 5: lose hope 
Here is where I'm stuck. What's next on the road to DNF? Is there an easier way (not including truth tables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will simplify $$p \oplus q \oplus r$$ using $$a\oplus b \Longleftrightarrow (a \wedge \neg b) \vee (\neg a \wedge b),$$ in tiny tiny steps.
We have
$$\Big[\Big((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)\Big) \wedge \neg r\Big] \vee
 \Big[\neg\Big((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)\Big) \wedge r\Big] $$
which becomes
$$\Big[\Big((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)\Big) \wedge \neg r\Big] \vee
 \Big[\Big(\neg(p \wedge \neg q) \wedge \neg(\neg p \wedge q)\Big) \wedge r\Big] $$
then
$$\Big[\Big((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)\Big) \wedge \neg r\Big] \vee
 \Big[\Big((\neg p \vee q) \wedge ( p \vee \neg q)\Big) \wedge r\Big] $$
then
$$\Big[\Big((p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r)\Big)\Big] \vee
 \Big[\Big((\neg p \vee q) \wedge ( p \vee \neg q)\Big) \wedge r\Big] $$
and the coup de grace by way of
$$ \Big((\neg p \vee q) \wedge ( p \vee \neg q)\Big) \Longleftrightarrow \big(\neg p \wedge (p\vee\neg q)\big) \vee \big(q \wedge (p\vee\neg q) \big) \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\wedge\neg q)\vee(p\wedge q)$$
is
$$\Big[\Big((p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r)\Big)\Big] \vee
 \Big[\Big( (\neg p\wedge\neg q)\vee(p\wedge q)\Big) \wedge r\Big] $$
becoming
$$\Big[\Big((p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r)\Big)\Big] \vee
 \Big[\Big( (\neg p\wedge\neg q\wedge r)\vee(p\wedge q\wedge r)\Big) \Big] $$
and finally
$$(p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r) \vee
 (\neg p\wedge\neg q\wedge r)\vee(p\wedge q\wedge r).$$
Which is exactly what we expect.

Comment: very awesome. can you tell me a little bit more about the coup de grace? it seems that you are distributing the not p and q over the second parenthesis. what rule does this use?

Comment: I would say we're distributing $(p\vee\neg q)$ over the LHS, not the other way around. I.e., $(a \vee b) \wedge (c \vee d) \rightarrow a \wedge (c \vee d) \vee b \wedge (c \vee d)$. I'm sure you can distribute the other way around and get the same result.

Comment: If you think this is a good answer, don't forget to upvote and select it.

Comment: ah, of course. unfortunately, my reputation doesn't yet permit me to upvote yet.

Comment: in the step from the penultimate line to the last line, i've seen that done with ANDs because of some commutative property, but does it also apply to strings of ORs?

Comment: It does apply -- I didn't think that needed a rule to justify it.  It seems obvious (a dangerous word) that $a\vee (b\vee c) \longrightarrow a\vee b \vee c$.

Comment: ive seen $a \vee (b \vee c) yields b \vee (a \vee c)$, but I hadn't seen it written such that all the ors or to each element